# Error: file ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod” not found while installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, grubrescue, usb-installation

I’m trying to install Ubuntu on an external ssd but every time I boot from the USB it suddenly loads grub rescue showing the error file ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod” not found  I searched a lot and I can’t find a solution.

I tried different  PC and everything but nothing seems to work.

I don’t think it’s a pen drive problem because I already installed Ubuntu on my older PC and it worked.

I also tried with command ls but it seems to read only pc hdd and it doesn’t recognize nothing as ext apart from a partition which is fat.

In bios the boot order is correct (I think) with the USB boot first and the PC HDD last.

To build the ISO in the pen drive I’m using Rufus that always worked fine for me, balena etcher return every time some error.

I’m stuck here for days and I don’t know what to do.

I also tried to install other distro like garuda and it seems to work fine (I didn’t complete the installation).

If anyone is able to help me, he will be my hero :)

Comment: Be aware of bug 1396379 -- Grub wrong disk https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  Do add yourself to the bug's "Does this affect me?" list (upper left corner). Several workarounds are in the bug, and links to other questions with solutions.

Comment: I think that I recall simply copying /i386-pc from the ISO to /boot/grub/ on the USB, and it worked okay.